# Best way to plot heatmap for rainfall data

Tags: maps, data-visualization, heatmap

So I am working on a Machine Learning project of rainfall prediction. For now I am working on visualizing the data I have. So, I have daily rainfall data from 1951 - 2007 for 84 different weather sites. So now given some particular year and month I want to plot a heatmap of average rainfall during that month and year across different sites. Also this heatmap should be plotted on a geological map. What is the best approach to build such plots. It'll be better if someone can suggest me any already existing library.

Answer (score 0):

To get started quickly, try PowerMap for Excel.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Get-started-with-Power-Map-88a28df6-8258-40aa-b5cc-577873fb0f4a

http://geoawesomeness.com/geoawesomehowto-how-to-make-a-killer-map-using-excel-in-under-5-minutes-with-powermap-plugin/

Even if that doesn't meet your needs completely, you should be able to test ideas quickly.